# Can anybody recommend a good mid-week winter mountaineering course or a good mountain guide in the Lake District, UK?

Tags: uk, training, crampons, winter-walking, ice-axes

Me and my partner will be spending a week in February in the Lake District, UK (Monday to Friday).  We want to get as much walking in as possible and attempt a number of the peaks / ridges.  We are very aware that we will find heavy snow and cold temperatures and that crampons / ice axes are recommended for that time of year.  Neither of us have experience of using crampons and ice axes.

We've had a look at the local centers who offer courses, and they all offer 2 day courses where they show you how to use the equipment and how to stay safe.  However all the courses run at weekends.

Does anybody know of a mid-week course?
Or alternatively, does anybody know of a good guide we could hire for a few days to guide us on some of the hikes and show us the techniques along the way?

Comment: I could of given you details of Snowdonia and Scotland but not the lakes, sorry. This sin't a very good fit for the SE Q&A format either. It's likely to become obsolete very quickly. I would recommend reading the [Mountain Leader winter skills book](http://www.joe-brown.com/7176/products/winter-skills---essential-walking-and-climbing-techniques.aspx?origin=pla&kwd=&currency=GBP&gclid=CjwKEAiAlb6lBRCBw4jC-bb3uykSJAB55Ti9RfmKdmm5p2MuT_RwE2ZyY8Qo7rMFNazOe2VXCLPotBoCLtfw_wcB) but probably back it up with some practical lessons too.